# VBO texturing don't work correctly LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, vbo

I try to use VBO to render my 3d objects.

I've created this class :

```
public class Object3DTexturedRendered {

private TextureRendered texture;
private int vboId = 0;
private int vboiId = 0;
private int vbotId = 0;
private int verticesTexCoords[][];
private int verticesIndex[];
private FloatBuffer verticesBuffer;
private FloatBuffer texturesBuffer;
private IntBuffer indexBuffer;

public Object3DTexturedRendered() {

}

public Object3DTexturedRendered(TextureRendered _texture) {
    texture = _texture;
}

public void renderVBO() {
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    if (texture.getTexture() != null) {
        texture.getTexture().bind();
    }

    ARBVertexBufferObject.glBindBufferARB(ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vboId);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

    ARBVertexBufferObject.glBindBufferARB(ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vbotId);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    ARBVertexBufferObject.glBindBufferARB(ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vboiId);
    glDrawRangeElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, (verticesIndex.length - 1), verticesIndex.length,
                                          GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0L);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    ARBVertexBufferObject.glBindBufferARB(ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);
    ARBVertexBufferObject.glBindBufferARB(ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}

public void initRenderVBO(FloatPointRendered[] listPointsRendered, int _verticesTexCoords[][], int _verticesIndex[]) {
    verticesTexCoords = _verticesTexCoords;
    verticesIndex = _verticesIndex;

    verticesBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(verticesTexCoords.length * 3);
    texturesBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(verticesTexCoords.length * 2);
    for (int[] _ipoint : verticesTexCoords) {
        FloatPointRendered _point = listPointsRendered[_ipoint[0]];
        float[] uv = texture.getXYtoFloat(_ipoint[1], _ipoint[2]);
        verticesBuffer.put(_point.positionToFloatArray());
        texturesBuffer.put(uv);
    }
    verticesBuffer.flip();
    texturesBuffer.flip();

    indexBuffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(verticesIndex.length);
    indexBuffer.put(verticesIndex);
    indexBuffer.flip();

    if (GLContext.getCapabilities().GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object) {
        IntBuffer vboID = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(3);
        ARBVertexBufferObject.glGenBuffersARB(vboID);
        vboId = vboID.get(0);
        ARBVertexBufferObject.glBindBufferARB(ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vboId);
        ARBVertexBufferObject.glBufferDataARB(ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, verticesBuffer, ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);

        vbotId = vboID.get(1);
        ARBVertexBufferObject.glBindBufferARB(ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vbotId);
        ARBVertexBufferObject.glBufferDataARB(ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, texturesBuffer, ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);

        vboiId = vboID.get(2);
        ARBVertexBufferObject.glBindBufferARB(ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vboiId);
        ARBVertexBufferObject.glBufferDataARB(ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, indexBuffer, ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);
    }
}
```

My object are all rendered correctly, but I've a problem with the texture.
My texture are strided. Look at this image... why my texture are like that, and how I can fixe this bugs.

[battleofground.fr_game_render_error_vbo_texture.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZbaI.png)

Comment: Resolved !

In fact, I cut not correctly my texture into my GL_TRIANGLES rendered !

Comment: On Stack Overflow, we don't put "SOLVED" in titles. If you've solved your problem, then post the solution as an answer for other people to see, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved !

In fact, I cut not correctly my texture into my GL_TRIANGLES rendered, so the texture coordinates were not correctly calculated to be applied in the GL_TRIANGLES !

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful.  - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12329676)

Comment: It's not a "thank you" answer. I've writen what has fixed my bug. Because my texture coords were not correctly calculated to be applied into the GL_TRIANGLES rendered. I've edited my answer for add more precisions.